# Create FormGroup by using reuse structure f componenets

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to create some FormGroups with the same definition. Therefore, i created a const with the structure:

```
export const predefinedFormGroup = {
  'field1': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
  'field2': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
  'field3': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
  'field4': new FormControl(null)
};
```

i need this as an object because i am not only using this to create the formgroup, i also making some iterations over the fields for other purposes.

Then, i am creating the FormGroup by using this method:

```
this.form = new FormGroup(predefinedFormGroup)
```

it works but with one big problems:

When the use type information on the fields, the cost is changing because TypeScript pass the predefinedFormGroup by reference, so the next time i am using the save line `this.form = new FormGroup(predefinedFormGroup)`to create another formGroup with the same structure, the form is dirty with the values the use filled in the first formGroup.

I know that i can use form.reset() to clear the values but i'm sure there is a better way to pass structure to FormGroup by val.

Can someone please help with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create factory function instead of variable

```
export const predefinedFormGroupFactory = () => ({
    field1: new FormControl(null, [...]),
    field2: new FormControl(null, [...])
})
```

And use it like

```
const predefinedGroup = predefinedFormGroupFactory();
this.form = new FormGroup(predefinedGroup);
```

Comment: I am getting the following error:

Argument of type '() => { 'field1': FormControl; 'field2': FormControl; 'field3': FormControl; '...' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }'.
  Index signature is missing in type '() => { 'field1': FormControl; 'field2': FormControl; 'field3': FormControl; '...'.

Comment: please help, i am getting the above error on compilation time.

Comment: Hm, I think you don't call `predefinedFormGroupFactory` function. Can you show your function definition and usage